# Wordpress Theme Customizer - Add area for users to move around and organize widgets

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am currently developing a Wordpress Theme, using the Theme Customizer to let users customize it, but I have got stuck.

For the footer, I have created various widgets, containing different things like Recent Posts, or a Live Twitter Feed.

I want the users to be able to organize them, in the order they want, yet I cannot work out how to do it. I found one other theme (Zerif Lite), that lets you do this (see image below), however I went through all the code and couldn't work out they did it, there was nothing adding the 'Our focus section widgets' section.

I have organized my theme similarly, there are various Panels, with Sections, and I want one of those sections to contain it.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Not everyone seems to get my problem. **I KNOW how to create Widgets**

I know how to create Widgets. I want an area in the Theme Customizer for users to **move them around**, not just the ones I created, but also other default ones like the Tag Cloud.

**EDIT 2:** @Codeartist, I am using Wordpress 4.3.1, and here is my code in `functions.php`

```
function widgets_init_mysite() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'widgets_init_mysite' );

function mytheme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_for_widgets', array(
        'priority'       => 70,
        'title'          => __('Panel for widgets', 'codeartist'),
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1' )->panel = 'panel_for_widgets';

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customizer' );
```

Comment: Have you looked into their code?

Comment: Yes, I spend ages trying to find it. I could see the 'Content' section they added, yet there was no section for 'Our focus section widgets'. I also looked through the other files but could see nothing.

Comment: Does your theme coming with a plugin ? Most of them are declared in a plugin with this king of code : class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

Comment: @Bipbip I am the one developing the theme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking inside `zerif_customizer.js`, I discovered that Zerif Lite is adding the widget panel sections to the Theme Customizer via JavaScript.

To do the same in a child theme of Zerif Lite...

In your `functions.php` file:

```
function mytheme_customizer_live_preview() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'mytheme-themecustomizer',                                  //Give the script an ID
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-customizer.js', //Point to file
        array( 'jquery' ),                                          //Define dependencies
        true                                                        //Put script in footer?
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_customizer_live_preview' );
```

Then put a new JavaScript file in your theme, where the filename and path must match the second parameter from the function above:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* Move our widgets into the widgets panel */
    wp.customize.bind('ready', function() {
        wp.customize.section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-mysection' ).panel( 'panel_mysection' );
        wp.customize.section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-mysection' ).priority( '2' );
    });
});
```

Of course, `panel_mysection` must already exist as per something like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_mysection', array(
    'priority' => 33,
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'title' => __( 'Mysection section', 'mytheme' )
));
```

And the `sidebar-mysection` widget section must already exist:

```
class zerif_mysection extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'ctUp-ads-widget',
            __( 'Zerif - Mysection widget', 'zerif-lite' )
        );
    }
}
function mytheme_register_widgets() {
    register_widget('zerif_mysection');
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name'          => 'Mysection section widgets',
            'id'            => 'sidebar-mysection',
            'before_widget' => '',
            'after_widget'  => ''
        )
    );
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'mytheme_register_widgets');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 6):

I was experimenting on freshly updated Twenty Eleven theme.

In function.php there were registered some sidebars:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Showcase Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'description' => __( 'The sidebar for the optional Showcase Template', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer Area One', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-3',
    'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer Area Two', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-4',
    'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer Area Three', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-5',
    'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'twentyeleven' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Each sidebar have its own unique id. If widgets and sidebars are enabled in your theme, then default 'widgets' panel would be created by Wordpress on customizer screen. Then for each sidebar would be created section placed in 'widgets' panel. That section has id based on sidebar id. And that id looks like this

```
sidebar-widgets-[sidebar-id]
```

Where sidebar-id is an id of respective sidebar.

All your code should be placed in functions.php (or inside plugin) in 'customize_register' hook

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'codeartist_customize_register' );
function codeartist_customize_register($wp_customize) {
    //Put your code here
}
```

So, basically, what we need to do is to create new panel

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'panel_for_widgets', array(
    'priority'       => 70,
    'title'          => __('Panel for widgets', 'codeartist'),
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
));
```

And then move in that panel all sections which represents sidebars.

```
$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1' )->panel = 'panel_for_widgets';
$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-2' )->panel = 'panel_for_widgets';
$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-3' )->panel = 'panel_for_widgets';
$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-4' )->panel = 'panel_for_widgets';
$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-5' )->panel = 'panel_for_widgets';
```

In Twenty Eleven there are five sidebars, so we move five sections.

Finally, the name of each section is the same as name of respective sidebar. To change description of the section you can do something like this.

```
$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1' )->description= __('New description', 'codeartist');
```

Sadly, there is not much documentation on get_section, but here is the link to codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/get_section

Comment: I can create the sidebars, but the Widgets Panel is not created. I can still add widgets to those sidebars from the menu in `wp-admin.php` via: Apperance -> Widgets. Do you know how I can get the Widgets Panel to be created? The second part of the code works fine, I can use it to move my existing sections around.

Comment: P.S. if you can, I'll award the bounty to you (but don't take too long, it ends in a couple of days)

Comment: So far as I know, widget sections only shows up if there is respective sidebar (may be empty without widgets, but still there) visible in live preview on the right.

So, if there is no visible sidebars on the main page (customizer preview always starts with index page) try to navigate to page where your sidebars are located.

So far as i investigated, Wordpress detects sidebar visible if one or both `is_active_sidebar()` or `dynamic_sidebar()` functioins (with respective sidebar id) is used on the page.

Comment: Notice, that widgets panel is automatically hidden if there is no sidebar section inside of it.

Comment: I have added the code `dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )` to my index.php (the page shown in the customizer), but the widgets panel is still not showing up?

Comment: I can even add widgets to the sidebars through Appearance -> Widgets, and they show up on the page, normally and in the theme customizer, so I know the sidebar is active.

Comment: Could you show me your code where you register sidebars? What hook? What file? Version of WP? Is 'widgets' panel active on clean Twenty Eleven theme in your Wordpress? Also try temporary  remove all your custom manipulation with customizer and look is 'widgets' panel appears or not with a clean setup?

Comment: I edited my answer, it now shows my code. I am using Wordpress 4.3.1

Comment: In the customizer, the Widgets panel is not appearing, how can I get it to appear?

Comment: @Druzion did you manage to make it work? This worked perfectly for me :) But I would like to know if there's a way to choose which widgets to show in the "Add widget" list. In fact, it would be great if I could choose a couple of custom widgets I've done myself for my theme.

Comment: @D'Tails Well, I carried on developing the theme, and suddenly the Widget panel popped up. I haven't tried it but I think it will work with me now. I don't think it is possible to choose which widgets show in the 'Add Widget' list, but I will try and find out (it would be extremely useful for me, it is an idea I did not even think of)

Comment: Then I guess we're together in this, @Druzion :) I'll be working on this today too, so I'll keep you posted if I manage to get closer to what we're aiming for ;)

Comment: I am working on the same problem mentioned in the OP.   I am also working on the same theme as mentioned in the OP, Zerif Lite.    I did a text file search for `get_section` in this entire theme and no matches are found!  It's still a mystery how this theme is getting the widget panel to show up in the theme customizer.

Comment: @Druzion, I figured out how the Zerif is doing it.  Look for `wp.customize.section()` in the `zerif_customizer.js` JavaScript file.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks! I have found it. It is basically doing what this answer says, but using JavaScript. Give me a few minutes to test it out.....

Comment: @Sparky It works! Thanks so much! The only thing you cannot do is put it inside a section, but with a bit of clever jQuery, that is possible too. Post your answer and I will accept (and upvote) it!

Comment: @Druzion, I put mine inside a section looking exactly the same as Zerif Lite.  I posted a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking to work with is the Theme Customizer in WordPress, which has a unique set of hooks and an API around it.

Get started by working with this hook, the customize_register hook:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_register/

A fairly robust API has been built up around the theme customizer, and you can refer to this manual for documentation when working with it:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/

Comment: This does not answer my question whatsoever. Could you not get from the title, various mentions in the question, the tags and @Codeartist's answer that I already know how to use the theme customizer?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're looking to add your custom & default widgets to the Theme Customizer, right?  You do that through the theme customizer API, which uses the customize_register hook.  I gave you two links, one to the theme customizer API documentation and one to the primary hook that you'd use to add functionality to the theme customizer.

What I described in my post isn't "how to use the theme customizer" but how to extend it and add functionality to it, which -- as far as I can tell -- is what you're looking for.

Comment: I had already read all that documentation, and I had already made my widgets. I just did not know how to get a sidebar / widget area displayed. None of your links told me that.